# C++ only one constructor is called

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to understand rvalue reference.
This is the code I've written so far:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A(const char* str) {
        std::cout << str;
    }

    A(A&& other) {
        std::cout << "other";
    }
};

int main() {
    A m(A(A(A("hello"))));
}
```

The output is only `"hello"`, which makes me confused.

Since `A("hello")` is a temporary object passed to the second constructor, But the code output is as if only the first constructor is called.

I guess either this is a compiler optimization or i miss some details about constructors and rvalues.

Comment: Yes this is an optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a compiler/language(see latter) optimization.

As can be [seen here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5af66c166c726f25), this will output:

```
hello
```

Changing the standard from `-std=c++2a` to `-std=c++14` in the compiler options will still give you `hello` only, but in addition to the standard change if you also add:
`-fno-elide-constructors` to the options you should see what you're hoping for.

However, this option will no longer work if you specify C++17 or C++2a as standard as this elision has become mandatory in certain situations since those standards, your situation is one of those.

Answer (score 3):

What you observe is also known as [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), more precisely:

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:
>
> (...)
>
> - In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:
>
> T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x

which is exactly your case.

Note that the optimization is **mandatory** for C++17 onwards. It is optional for C++11, but it seems that your compiler applies it anyway.